# Using BlueSnap on more than one Magento store

Tags: payment-gateway, payment, magento2, bluesnap

I have a BlueSnap account that I use on a Magento 2 online store. It works well, but now I plan to open a separate Magento online store with a different domain. I don't know if it's possible to use the same BlueSnap account for the new store's payment gateway, or should I just open some sub-section in BlueSnap to handle the new business?

If I copy the setup of the Magento BlueSnap plugin to the new store I have a few issues - I get notifications to the old domain, for example. After a few test tries, I'm not sure how to set it up.

Does anyone have experience with this?

Answer (score 0):

there is no problem excepting payments from more then one store on the same bluesnap account.
the only issue that I can think of is with the notifications,
In your BlueSnap account, under settings-general settings you can Add a second IPN URL and define the URL of your second store. this will mean that all notifications will be sent to both of your stores.

I don't know if on magento side the BlueSnap plugin will ignore notifications on orders that where not made from the same store. 
If on your testing you just see the notification in the logs of your "original" store but there is no other affect, then you can add the URL of your new store to the notification settings and each store will handle the notifications that are relevant to the orders that where created on it only.